# TypeError: (X) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working on a simple React project. I am now trying to call the onClick function that calls the handleDelete function that enables to delete a blog item from its id.

Here is the BlogList component:

```
const BlogList = ({blogs,title,handleDelete}) => {
    return (
        <div className="blog-list">
            <h2>{ title }</h2>
                {blogs.map((blog) => (
                    <div className="blog-preview" key={blog.id}>
                        <h2>{ blog.title }</h2>
                        <p>written by { blog.author}</p>
                        <button onClick={() => handleDelete(blog.id)}>delete blog</button>
                    </div>
                ))}
        </div>
    );
}

export default BlogList;
```

Here is the Home component:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import BlogList from "./blogList";

const Home = () => {
    const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([
        { title: 'My new website', body: 'lorem ipsum...', author: 'mario', id: 1 },
        { title: 'Welcome party!', body: 'lorem ipsum...', author: 'yoshi', id: 2 },
        { title: 'Web dev top tips', body: 'lorem ipsum...', author: 'mario', id: 3 }
    ])

    const handleDelete = (id) => {
        const newBlogs = blogs.filter(blog => blog.id !== id);
        setBlogs(newBlogs);
    }

    return (
        <div className="home">
            <BlogList blogs={blogs} title='All blogs'/>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

When I click on the delete blog button in the browser, I receive this:

> messageTypeError: handleDelete is not a function

What am I missing here?

Comment: `<BlogList blogs={blogs} title='All blogs'/>` you're not passing `handleDelete` down as a prop. Do `<BlogList blogs={blogs} title='All blogs' handleDelete={handleDelete}/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass your handler as a prop to BlogList component. Like this:

```
<BlogList blogs={blogs} title='All blogs' handleDelete={handleDelete} />
```